# Automatic population of std::map with function pointers

Tags: c++, stl

I am developing a script language in C++ that uses functions that are "built-in" in the interpreter. I am using the following construction to map function names to their respective pointers:

```
typedef void(*BuiltInFunction)(Context*);
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, BuiltInFunction> BuiltinFunctionsMap;
```

where `Context` is a custom class.

Then I have function declarations like this:

```
namespace BuiltIns {
    void _f_print(Context* context);
    void _f_error(Context* context);
    void _f_readline(Context* context);
    void _f_read(Context* context);
    void _f_readchar(Context* context);
    void _f_eof(Context* context);
    ...
}
```

And finally a routine that fills the map with the actual pointers:

```
BuiltinFunctionsMap BuiltIns::populateFunctions() {
    BuiltinFunctionsMap funcMap;
    // Standard I/0
    funcMap["print"] = &BuiltIns::_f_print;
    funcMap["error"] = &BuiltIns::_f_error;
    funcMap["readline"] = &BuiltIns::_f_readline;
    funcMap["read"] = &BuiltIns::_f_read;
    funcMap["readchar"] = &BuiltIns::_f_readchar;
    funcMap["eof"] = &BuiltIns::_f_eof;
    ...
    return funcMap;
}
```

What I am asking is if there is a way to generate the population function automatically from the function declaration using templates or something similar. Currently, I am using a regular expression, which is simple enough but I have to do it whenever I add new functions and it is cumbersome.

Comment: I am quite new to C++. I'd be very happy to consider a better solution :)

Comment: `std::function` is your friend. It can be a function pointer- or a function object, which means that it can be many, many things. Function pointers are incredibly restrictive, whereas `std::function` permits much freedom.

Comment: If you can do it with regular expressions, can't you add that as a step in your build process ?

Comment: @alexisdm: I can, of course, but I thought that maybe C++ offers me a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is really a helpful answer, but you can use the preprocessor to do some [pretty squirrelly stuff](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401387):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Context {}; 
typedef void (*BuiltInFunction)(Context*);

// a list of your function names
#define FN_NAMES \
X(foo)  \
X(bar)  \
X(baz)

// this declares your functions (you also have to define them 
// somewhere else, e.g. below or in another file)
#define X(a) void _f_ ## a ## _print(Context *context);
namespace BuiltIns {
  FN_NAMES
}
#undef X

// a global map initialized (using C++11's initializer syntax)
// to strings mapped to functions
#define X(a) {#a, &BuiltIns::_f_ ## a ## _print},
std::map<std::string, BuiltInFunction> g_fns = { 
  FN_NAMES
};
#undef X

int main() {
  g_fns["foo"](NULL);  // calls BuiltIns::_f_foo_print(NULL) 
}

// (these have to be defined somewhere)
namespace BuiltIns {
  void _f_foo_print(Context *context) {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
  }
  void _f_bar_print(Context *context) {
    std::cout << "bar\n";
  }
  void _f_baz_print(Context *context) {
    std::cout << "baz\n";
  }
}
```

This approach has the benefit of automatically generating e.g. the string `"foo"` and tying it to the `_f_foo_print` function.  The downsides are horrible preprocessor trickery and the fact that you still have to deal with `foo` in two places.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically detect *some* kinds of functions using template metaprogramming- for example, given a type T, you can programatically answer the question "Does T have an `operator+`?". But in the general case, you cannot do what you're doing above automatically in the language.